# Why is my NSMenuItem is disabled when it has an action?

Tags: swift, appkit, nsmenu, nsmenuitem, nstoolbaritem

I'm implementing a custom `NSToolbarItem` that has a button and a dropdown, like Mail. The only thing that's not working, though, is that the `NSMenuItem` is disabled. Whatever I do, I can't get it enabled. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

```
class DropdownTypeToolbarItem: NSToolbarItem {
    private var handler: ((NSNumber) -> Void)?

    init(itemIdentifier: NSToolbarItem.Identifier, handler: ((NSNumber) -> Void)?) {
        super.init(itemIdentifier: itemIdentifier)

        self.handler = handler

        let control = NSSegmentedControl(labels: ["Open", ""],
                                         trackingMode: .momentary,
                                         target: self,
                                         action: #selector(open))

        let menu = NSMenu(title: "")
        menu.addItem(withTitle: "Export", action: #selector(export(_:)), keyEquivalent: "")

        control.setMenu(menu, forSegment: 1)
        control.setShowsMenuIndicator(true, forSegment: 1)

        self.view = control
    }

    @objc func open() {
        print("select open")
        self.handler?(0)
    }

    @objc func export(_ sender: Any) {
        print("select export")
        self.handler?(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [menu item is enabled, but still grayed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870141/menu-item-is-enabled-but-still-grayed-out)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSMenuItem is not enabled swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27984127/nsmenuitem-is-not-enabled-swift)

Answer (score 0):

The NSToolbarItem itself is not part of the responder chain, which is what's used to determine if the menu item *can* be enabled, when the `target` of the menu item is `nil`. In this case, you should just explicitly set the `target` of the menu iem to be the toolbar item.